# Javascript: Can I avoid closures?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an website. I am putting addEventListener to more elements in a function called more times:

```
    idImag = 0;

    function function1()
    {
        //do something
        function2()
    }

    function function2()
    {
        //do something
        document.getElementById("holder" + idImag).addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
         idImag++;
alert('It works');
    }

    function3(event)
    {
        alert(3);
    }

    function1();
    function1();

<div id="holder0">Dog</div>
<div id="holder1">Chicken</div>
<div id="holder2">Cow</div>
```

But there is a problem: Only the last element gets the event listener... the others do nothing after putting the mouse over it.
Then I've googled a little and found out about closures and how variables are kept even after function returned... I didn't understand everything, but I just want to find out how to put the event listeners in function2. Can you help me?
Probably you noticed: I am a newbie. Sorry if the question is stupid or if it has no sense. If you need more details, I will put my whole code, but it has variables and comments in Romanian, so I am not sure if you will understand it. Sorry for my bad English and thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you should add some more code. Your current code does not show any problems regarding event handlers.

Comment: The code seems to have been cut off, can you post the event handler function you give in addEventListener call?

Comment: Looks like it should work.  Perhaps you need `var idImag = 0;` at the top?  Not saying `var` should just mean `window.idImg`, so you could use that reference instead, and make sure `window.idImg` is incrementing

Comment: Besides, the `function3` function (?) does not parse and has nothing to do with the rest of it. Please post real, parse-able code.

Comment: Seriously, either post **valid** code that *actually* replicates your issue, or don't bother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not a for loop?

```
function function3 (event) {
    alert(3);
}

for (var idImag = 0; i< numberOfHolders; i++) {
    //do something1
    //do something2
    document.getElementById("holder" + idImag).addEventListener('mouseover',function3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just care about the image id, which is available through the id attribute of the element.

Thus you can do:

```
document.getElementById("holder" + idImag).addEventListener(
    'mouseover',
    function(){
        var id = this.id;
        /* Then strip off "holder" from the front of that string */
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct, in that it will call `document.getElementById("holder0").addEventListener(…)`, then it will call `document.getElementById("holder1").addEventListener(…)`. Closures aren't your problem there.

You can verify this by, eg, using `console.log` to log the element that you're adding the event listener to (you'll need Firebug installed, or Chrome's developer console open).

Maybe paste the code to http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can try it?